# How to access property mediator outside iterator which is defined inside iterator?

Tags: properties, scope, iterator, wso2, wso2-esb

I have treed as below

```
<iterate xmlns:oag="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/10" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" continueParent="true" preservePayload="true" attachPath="//ProcessCredit/DataArea" expression="//ProcessCredit/DataArea/Credit sequential="true">
.....
 <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                        xmlns:oa="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/10"
                        name="ChargeTransactionKey"
                        expression="concat(get-property('operation','ChargeTransactionKey'),//Extension/ValueText[@typeCode='Charge Transaction Key'],':')"
                        scope="operation"
                        type="STRING"
                        description="ChargeTransactionKey"/>
 ...........

</iterate >
<log level="full">
<property name="requestIdChargeTransactionKey"
                  expression="get-property('operation','ChargeTransactionKey')"/>
     </log>
```

but value in property "requestIdChargeTransactionKey" is null, it means I'm unable to capture the property  which is defined inside iterator.

can anybody help on syntax?

Comment: Someone, answer my question similar line [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46740841/wso2esb-accessing-variable-outside-iterator-mediator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46740841/wso2esb-accessing-variable-outside-iterator-mediator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mediation inside iterate works with clones of MessageContext. If you continue parent mediation (set continueParent attribute to true), you work with the initial MessageContext and therefore all the properties you have set with scope 'default' inside iterate are lost

But there is a scope named 'operation' used to retrieve a property in the operation context level and if you set a property with this scope inside iterate, you can get it's value in the parent mediation

Inside iterate :

```
<property name="ChargeTransactionKey" value="xxx" scope="operation"/>
```

In parent mediation :

```
get-property('operation','ChargeTransactionKey')
```

Comment: I have tried by making continueParent="false" in iterator but in console I'm getting warning " WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-39", even nothing is logged.

Comment: with continueParent="false", the mediation after iterate is not executed so, I guess that you doesn't send back a response to the caller.   Why are you using iterate mediator ? You musn't use it to apply transformations, but only if you want to execute the same mediation for a collection of nodes in your xml payload. If you call a service inside iterate, you will call it each time the given node appear in your xml and you will receive the same number of responses that you can aggregate if needed with aggregate mediator

Comment: I've just discovered that there is a scope named 'operation' that responds to your needs

Comment: My intention is to use property which is defined inside iterator needs to be accessed outside iterator for that I'm using operation scope of property, but I'm not achieving it.

Answer (score 0):

[WSO2 Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/XPath+Extension+Functions#XPathExtensionFunctions-operationscope), You can fetch the property in the operation context level from the operation scope.

The properties within iterated/cloned message with the operation scope are preserved in the sequence even if you have configured your API resources to be sent through the fault sequence when faults exist.

get-property('operation', String propertyName)

A given property with the operation scope only exists in a single request and can be accessed by a single resource. The properties in this scope are passed to the error handler when the [FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Generic+Properties#GenericProperties-SOAPfault) property is set to true