# wso2esb- accessing variable outside iterator mediator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wso2, wso2-esb

Basically, inside iterator, I am setting some variable using Script (name: setValue) mediator.  I am trying to access them in the Ruby script outside the iterator.

According to the documentation: [How to access property mediator outside iterator which is defined inside iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201264/how-to-access-property-mediator-outside-iterator-which-is-defined-inside-iterator)

Different options I tried:

1)  In Ruby script,  I tried using

```
$mc.get-property('Operation','githubhosturl1');  I am getting syntax error at operation.
```

2)  Outside Iterator  I tried accessing them using Property

```
<property   expression="get-property('operation','githubhosturl')  name="githubhosturl1)
```

**getting an error at expression.**

3)  In Ruby script I tried:

$mc.get-property('githubhosturl1') - Empty value returning

How can I solve this issue?

My code  - proxy service -  I am pasting only small portion, where there is an issue.  In setValue script I am able to print the value in the console log.

```
<Iterator>
-------
--------
-------
<script description="setValue" language="js"><![CDATA[var log = mc.getServiceLog(); 
            var tool =  mc.getProperty('toolList');

           if( tool == "github")
           {    
                var vhosturl = mc.getProperty('catName');
                mc.setProperty('githubhosturl',vhosturl.toString());
                var vassetid = mc.getProperty('assetidval');
                mc.setProperty('gitassetid',vassetid.toString());
                var vbranch="qa";
                mc.setProperty('gitbranch',vbranch.toString());
           }
           if( tool == "dockercloud")
           {
                var vhosturl = mc.getProperty('catName');
                mc.setProperty('dockerhosturl',vhosturl.toString());
                var vassetid = mc.getProperty('assetidval');
                mc.setProperty('dockerid',vassetid.toString());
                var creid = mc.getProperty('jsondata');
                mc.setProperty('doccredid',creid.toString());
                var vprojName = mc.getProperty('projName');
                mc.setProperty('docproj',vprojName.toString());
           }]]></script>
        <property expression="get-property('githubhosturl')" name="githubhosturl1" scope="operation" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="get-property('gitbranch')" name="gitbranch1" scope="operation" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="get-property('gitassetid')" name="gitassetid1" scope="operation" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="get-property('dockerhosturl')" name="dockerhosturl1" scope="operation" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="get-property('doccredid')" name="doccredid1" scope="operation" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="get-property('docproj')" name="docproj1" scope="operation" type="STRING"/>
    </sequence>
</target>
</iterate>
<script description="re" language="rb"><![CDATA[require 'erb'
     require 'erb'

     @giturl = $mc.getProperty('githubhosturl1');
      @gitbranch = $mc.getProperty('gitbranch1');
      @gitcredential = $mc.getProperty('gitassetid1');

      @dockerurl = $mc.getProperty('dockerhosturl1');
      @dockerCred = $mc.getProperty('doccredid1');
      @dockerprojectname = $mc.getProperty('docproj1');

      @template = File.read('C:\WS02\workspace\index.txt.erb')
      OutTemplate = ERB.new(@template).result( binding )

      File.open('C:\WS02\workspace\Jenkin.groovy',"w") do |f|
         f.puts OutTemplate
      end]]></script>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing all the scope inside the Iteration from "default" to "Operation"  and access them outside using  get-property('operation', variable) and then change the scope to "Default"